# Spring transactional method on test doesn't rollback

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-data

I want to know how transactions work in spring and more or less I've learned it (or I think I've learned it). The only thing a don't get is as follow: To check how rollback does its magic I created a test that call a method with @Transacional annotation that throw an exception and see if the method changes are save as seen from outside. To my surprise, the change appears to be committed.

This is the code:

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNull.nullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

import repositories.files.ArchivoEnDisco;
import repositories.files.ArchivosEnDiscoRepo;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = GhcserviceapiApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class PruebasSinTransacciones {

    @Autowired
    ArchivosEnDiscoRepo repositorio;

    @Test
    public void compruebaTransaccionSinVariable() {

        // I get one far away from the last.
        Long id = repositorio.count() + 10l;

        try {

            inTransacction(id);

            fail("Exception must be throw");

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        // I try to get the saved object
        ArchivoEnDisco aedOriginal = repositorio.findOne(id);

        assertThat("An exception ocurred so it doesn't have to find it", aedOriginal, nullValue());

    }

    @Transactional()
    private void inTransacction(Long id) throws Exception {

        repositorio.save(new ArchivoEnDisco(id, id + "A.txt"));

        throw new Exception();

    }

}
```

For me, as an exception is throw the transaction must rollback and therefore the save object doesn't need to exist in the repository. But when I run the test, the find method return the saved object. Could someone in what I'm wrong?

---

Note: `GhcserviceapiApplication` is a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. `ArchivosEnDiscoRepo` is a `CrudRepository`. And I have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `hsqldb` in my pom but jpa isn't configured (so I use in memory hsqldb).

---

**EDIT**

I've separated classes because of @M. Deinum comment, and also tried to use and specific `rollbackFor` parameter but the result is the same.

```
// ConTransacciones.java
// Also tried with Throwable.class
@Transactional(rollbackFor=CustomError.class)
public class ConTransacciones {

    public ArchivosEnDiscoRepo repositorio;

    public void enTransaccion(Long id) throws CustomError {

        repositorio.save(new ArchivoEnDisco(id, id + "A.txt"));

        throw new CustomError();

    }

}

// CustomError.java
public class CustomError extends Exception { }

// PruebasSinTransacciones.java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = GhcserviceapiApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class PruebasSinTransacciones {

    @Autowired
    ArchivosEnDiscoRepo repositorio;

    @Test
    public void compruebaTransaccionSinVariable() {

        ConTransacciones ct = new ConTransacciones();
        ct.repositorio = this.repositorio;

        Long id = repositorio.count() + 10l;

        try {

            ct.enTransaccion(id);

            fail("Debería haberse lanzado una excepción");

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        ArchivoEnDisco aedOriginal = repositorio.findOne(id);

        assertThat("La transacción no debería haber guardado el archivo", aedOriginal, nullValue());

    }

}
```

Comment: It is an internal method call so your `@Transactional` is pretty much useless. Next to that even if it wouldn't be it wouldn't work as that isn't how `@Transactional` works in a test case!. Also you aren't testing anything database related, you are only testing the first level cache. Finally `@Transactional` will by default only rollback on `RuntimeException`s not on `Exception`s.

Comment: Yes, I don't really trying to test my database, this test only a way to test what I suppose is how transactions are done. Could you explain what is the difference with @Transactional in tests?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Transaction rolls back only for Checked exceptions, AS the Exception is partially checked class, it's not rolled back the transaction.
You may use @Transactional(rollbackFor="Throwable.class").